# ng-animate reverts back to original class

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to set up a simple animation but for some reason my ng-animate reverts back to the .trailer status

http://plnkr.co/edit/X2zjosxSLgBpCxQAkdGJ?p=preview

When I click the trailer link I enter the `trailer` state,

```
<div ng-controller="trailerCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="trailer in trailers">
      <a href="#" ui-sref="trailer({trailer_title: '{{trailer.title}}'})">{{ trailer.title }}</a>
      {{ trailer.link }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div ui-view="trailer-container" class="trailer"></div>
</div>
```

This injects the template from the `trailer` state inside the `trailer-container` view element.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('');

  $stateProvider
    .state('trailer', {
      url: '',
      params: {
        trailer_title: null
      },
      views: {
        "trailer-container": {
          template: '<div>{{ trailer_title }}</div>',
          controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
            $scope.trailer_title = $stateParams.trailer_title
            console.log ($scope.trailer_title)
          }
        },
      }
    })
})
```

Then the `<div ui-view="trailer-container" class="trailer"></div>` gets the `ng-enter` and 'ng-enter-active`class and performs the animations. But once the animations are done it reverts back to the normal`trailer` class.

```
.trailer{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.trailer.ng-enter{
  transition: all 5s;
  height: 0px
}

.trailer.ng-enter-active{
  height: 700px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

So how I can I stop the animation from reverting back?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is expected behaviour. By adding in another state `('home')` and then adding a class to the injected template `.big` and give that class a height it stays at the correct height.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: ''
    })

  $stateProvider
    .state('trailer', {
      url: '',
      params: {
        trailer_title: null
      },
      views: {
        "trailer-container": {
          template: '<div class="large">{{ trailer_title }}</div>',
          controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
            $scope.trailer_title = $stateParams.trailer_title
            console.log ($scope.trailer_title)
          }
        },
      }
    })
})
```

css

```
.trailer{
  background-color: red;
}

.trailer.ng-enter{
  transition: all 2s;
  height: 0px;
}

.trailer.ng-enter.ng-enter-active{
  height: 300px;
}

.large{
  height: 300px;
}
```